# Chrome Metro Switch windows shortcut

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, modern-ui

Is there a shortcut to switch between Chrome windows in Windows 8.1 Metro mode?

Normally I'd do it with a <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, but in this case that does not work cause the browser window are all inside a single Window's window

Comment: It's CTRL+TAB like in any other browser

Comment: @nixda - This happens to be the shortcut in the desktop version also.

Comment: like DonQuiyote stated in his answear, i know how to switch tabs. it's a pretty basic chrome shortcut, but i don't know how to switch windows. Can't do that with alt+tab cause that's the windows shortcut, so how should i do it? can't be that the only way is to always minimize/maxmize windows.

Answer (score 9):

To switch between tabs you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

To switch between windows you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

Comment: Alt + 1 only goes to the first window?